# can jQuery read the id value after a question mark:"anyurl.com?nid=44"

Tags: jquery

I need to use an if condition that reads the value of the nid after a ?nid=44 in the address bar. Can it be done with jQuery?

Comment: Have a look at this question -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript. There's various methods explained in there that will get you what you want.

Comment: No, jQuery has no support for reading the query string, you would do that using plain Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably jQuery itself can't do this. But exists plugins:

[PARSEQUERY](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/parseQuery)

[QUERY STRING OBJECT](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object)

Also it was discussion on the stackoverflow about it: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)